# How to use FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg, mediametadataretriever

I have used FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever in "Eclipse" with fmmr.jar file it's working fine but right now I have migrated my project in "Android Studio". I used following dependencies in my build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.5'
```

}

but I found the following error

```
03-30 16:07:10.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7763): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libavutil.so.54" needed by "libswscale.so"; caused by library "libavutil.so.54" not found
03-30 16:07:10.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7763): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
03-30 16:07:10.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7763): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
03-30 16:07:10.030: E/AndroidRuntime(7763): at wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.<clinit>(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.java:124)
```

please suggest me how to resolved this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in version 1.0.9:

```
compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.9'
```

Comment: now it gives   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: Use compile 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever:1.0.9'

Comment: it was eclipse project when i added fmmr library ,then i migrated to studio ,everything was fine ,but it causes crashing on some devices.